# AngularJS - Conditionally apply an attribute?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Conditionally applying an element is easy - just use ng-show.  But what about an attribute?

IE

```
<div ui-sortable>
  ...
</div>
```

needs to be sortable only for admins, so do something like...

```
<div ng-conditional-attribute=" {'ui-sortable': 'user.isAdmin()'} ">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom directive or template and switch between the version with sortable attached and the version without.

Comment: This is definitely a good solution.  But in the interest of DRY, looking for something that uses less code.

Comment: Whatever route you take, you'll fundamentally have to write a new directive. You COULD just use `ui-if` on 2 variations, but the children DOM would still be repeated. Create a custom directive and conditionally add the property. If the priority is higher than sortable it _should_ work fine

Comment: Okay.  That's not too bad.  Thank you.

Comment: @ProLoser you mind giving an example of that? I would also like to have `<div ui-sortable="sortableOptions">` if `admin` is truthy, and `<div>` if it is not. How would you write a directive to do that?

Comment: Anyone got a more up to date solution for this? Scratching my head!!

Answer (score 1):

Since a lot of directives also work from `class` you might be able to use `ng-class="{'ui-sortable': user.isAdmin()}"`.

I don't know enough about the `angular-ui` directives to know what restrictions they have

Comment: You know what, that's an interesting idea I didn't think about. There's no real reason I can think of that the restrictions should prevent use in classes. It might be worth testing.

Comment: After thinking about it (and a little more testing) I realized this won't work. The location of all directives is cached at compile time, and since this class isn't present at compile time, the directive is never binded

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but it may help someone:

```
ng-readonly =""
```

will set the attribute if the expression is truthy.

There are a number of other ng attributes that work this way.